# Click not registering in a selection list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a group of divs that form a selection list inside of vert. scrolling div.
It is impossible to click on any of the items beyond those that are initially visible in the list.

When it works, the variable will be displayed in the input box & the selection will collapse.

Currently, it doesn't work, it just goes back the start of the list and nothing else happens.

Demo: http://www.partiproductions.com/searchertest2/index.html

I've tried a helper function, but it doesn't seem to be registering the click.
What do I need to change in my code to fix this?

```
$(function() {
   $('#SearcherBar_stacks_in_1_page0 .ac_results div').click(function() {
      var clterm = $(this).children("span").attr("class");
      console.log('Clicked: ' + clterm);
      $('input#select_searcher_stacks_in_1_page0.ac_input').val(clterm).trigger('keyup');
   });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: first of all, something wrong with selectors: it's not valid notation %id%. Did you mean $('#SearcherBar_stacks_in_1_page0')  ?

Comment: Good eye. That's a notation for a plugin which converts it to something like 'stacks_in_1_page0' before it's published. What you see on the page is the finished names ;)